# Is this main box outdated and needs upgrade?

Tags: electrical, safety, electrical-panel, electrical-distribution

This house is 1970's built (UK) but not sure when the electrical wiring were done. The main box looks like in the attached picture. It seems it has only fuse boxes in it... and does not have any MCB, RCD (Residual current device).

Should this be upgraded ? Is it very unsafe ?
Any idea how much would it cost ?
Can this be done only by electicity supplier or any local electrician ?

[image]